# My Mac laptop won't recognize the Nexus player connected to it

Tags: android, android-tv

I turned on all relevant developer options, but my laptop never recognizes the player when I hook it up over USB. No "Allow debugging from this laptop RSA etc."

Comment: Developping an Android app on a Mac is like drinking coffee in a plastic cup

Comment: I've been able to get all my other Android devices recognized by my laptop, no troubles.

Comment: Any luck with this one? Having the exact same problem. I have three other android devices that adb detects no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

- Restarting each device
- Restarting ADB
- Toggling USB debugging
- Removing all debugging certificates
- Using a different USB cable

Comment: Yes, I did. I even called tech support for Google and for Apple. Nothing.